# Get path from property in m.table

Tags: sapui5

I'm looking for a convenient method to get the path from a table cell.

**Background:** It is required to implement a search field allowing to filter on all columns of responsive table. Here, the path is needed as parameter for the filter object.

#### XML Code

```xml
<Table items="{path: 'modelName>pathPart1/pathPart2'}">
  <headerToolbar>
    <Toolbar>
      <Title text="titleText"/>
      <SearchField search="searchInTable"/>
    </Toolbar>
  </headerToolbar>
  <columns>
    <Column>
      <Text text="column1"/>
    </Column>
    <Column>
      <Text text="column2"/>
    </Column>
  </columns>
  <ColumnListItem>
    <Text text="{modelName>cellName1}"/>
    <Text text="{modelName>cellName2}"/>
  </ColumnListItem>
</Table>
```

#### Controller Logic

```js
searchInTable: function(event) {
  var table = event.getSource().getParent().getParent();
  var query = event.getParameters("query");
  table.getBinding("items").filter(this.getFilters(table, query));
},

getFilters: function(table, query) {
  var aFilters = [];
  var items = table.getItems();
  // Loop  through items aggregation and populate filter object
  jQuery.each(items, function(i, oItem) {
    // Get path from cells (e.g. cellName1)
    var sPath = oItem.mAggregations.cells[i].mBindingInfos.text.binding.sPath;
    var sOperator = FilterOperator.EQ;
    var sValue1 = query;
    var oFilter = new Filter(sPath, sOperator, sValue1);
    aFilters.push(oFilter);
  });
  return aFilters;
},
```

Can we replace this part by a more convenient and robust method?

> ```
> var sPath = oItem.mAggregations.cells[i].mBindingInfos.text.binding.sPath;
> ```

As you notice, I'm trying to receive the `sPath` going through the whole object. However, its not working in all cases as the structure of the object may change. I bet there is an better approach available. However, I struggling a bit here.

Any ideas?

Edit: I do like to get the path pointing to the text property in the table. In this samplle it would be: cellName2

Comment: Are the cells going to be **always** `sap.m.Text`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm on the phone right now, so I can't test it, but it is something like this

`oItem.getCells()[i].getBindingContext().getPath()`

getCells() comes from the ColumnListItem API if I am not wrong.

The other two from the ODataListBinding API or something like that...

If you dive a bit in the API you will find it

EDIT: I think you should provide the model name when getting the context. But I don't remember well...

`oItem.getCells()[i].getBindingContext("modelName").getPath()`

Try both, with and without it...

EDIT2: Here you have the snippet http://jsbin.com/votaxiyedi/edit?html,output

And this what you need:

`oItem.getBindingContext("odata").getPath() + "/" + oItem.getCells()[0].getBinding("text").getPath();`

Comment: In fact you are right and by providing the statement above we receive the pathto item aggregation. Taken the sample above it looks similar like: "pathPart1/pathPart2/0", "pathPart1/pathPart2/1", "pathPart1/pathPart2/2" etc. However, I would like to have the path applied to the property (in this sample its called "cellName1", "cellName2" etc.).

Comment: I don't know exactly what you mean by "the property"  but, for sure, when you use what I said before, you get the path to the context binded to the cell, this means the "pathPart1/pathPart2/0", "pathPart1/pathPart2/1", "pathPart1/pathPart2/2" ... nodes of your model...

Comment: However, inside your cell, if you have text, then I guess you have another control, like sap.m.Text for example. If you want to get the path for the binded 'text' property of the sap.m.Text control for example, you need to get the control from the cell, something like `oText = oItem.getCells()[i].getItems()[j]` and then get the binding of the text property, I think it is something like: `oPath = oText.getBinding('text').getPath()`

Comment: I need to check it, but I have no access to a computer these days... Try something similar and if no success I will give you a snippet in 3 o 4 days

Comment: Sorry, I just realize that you provided the XML code as well... definitely, once you get the cell, get the items inside (not sure if it is `getItems()` or `getContent()`, it should return an array with one object. This object should be a sap.m.Text instance, so you can get the path binded to its text property as I said before